# Copy/Paste attribute table qgis without the wkt_geom column?

Tags: qgis, excel, table, copy

Is there a way to copy the attribute table on qgis and paste it on excel without the wkt_geom column? [image]

Comment: do you want to copy the whole attribute table or a selection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

In Settings> Options> Data Sources:

[image]

Copy features as:

"Plain text, no geometry"